# XCode Documentation - Offline Reading

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

Is it possible to have the iOS and OSX documentation available for offline reading? If so, how?

Comment: (http://kapeli.com/dash)  as a workaround

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Documentation for iOS is no longer a part of SDK for offline reading - looks like you need to install from preferences of XCode, select Documentation preferences - click get next to 'iOS 4.3 Library Documentation' to install it.

Answer (score 8):

As of Xcode 5, you can choose to download sets of documentation under Preferences\Downloads Tab\Documentation.

[image: XCode Downloads Tab]

Answer (score 7):

Go to Xcode's documentation preferences, and make sure that any documentation set you're going to need offline doesn't have a Get button next to it.  If it does, click the button to download the set while you're online.

Answer (score 1):

A lot, if not most, of the online documentation has a link to a PDF of what you're reading in the top right of the window, underneath the Search icon.

Comment: those pdfs are useful if there are just one or two items you want the docs for - but what if you want a whole section? there must be a better way than downloading hundreds of pdfs one by one.

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 7+, you can find the download for the documentation in Preferences > Components.

[image]

You have to download documentation for every OS (macOS, watchOS, iOS, tvOS) separately.

Comment: This tab only has "Simulators" for me. Did they change it? How do I download documentation in the recent version? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When in XCode press **⌘ + ⌥ + ⇧ + /** then start searching for methods or classes you're interested in.