# IOS Dev Library offline on you mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, class-reference

I need a offline version of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

Does something like this exist? thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already got an offline version of the Doc, if you have Xcode installed in your system.

In `Xcode`, goto `Help --> Developer Documentation`. *Shortcut*: `Option + Command + ?`. This will show you the documentation page loaded in *Xcode* itself. Select the `Home` button at the top of the toolbar. It will show a drop down list of reference libraries available. Select iOS library from the menu. It will show you the page you want.

In Xcode, `Option + Double-Click on a symbol`: Opens the doc for the selected symbol in a small window. Clicking on the book-like-button, the second button from the top-right corner of the window opens the reference page of the symbol. That button is enabled only if the documentation available for the symbol.

Answer (score 0):

A more up to date question and answer:  [XCode Documentation - Offline Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151124/xcode-documentation-offline-reading)

The shotcuts Simon describes still work, but the Help menu has changed.