# Documentation download from within XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am watching Objective-C tutorials, and they are all old for obvious reasons.
During their times, it was possible to download documentation in XCode for offline reference--in the way discussed in this question:
[XCode Documentation - Offline Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151124/xcode-documentation-offline-reading)

It used to be done via `Preferences` -> `Downloads` tab -> `Documentation`. I.e., you used to have both Documentation and Simulators in the `Downloads` tab.

In the recent version of XCode there is no `Downloads` tab. There is only `Components` tab, and it only has Simulators, no Documentation.

I tried searching for the answer, but surprisingly no luck for such seemingly simple question.

How do I download the full set of available docs for offline use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is available out of the box nowadays and can be accessed from `Window - Developer Documentation (⇧⌘0)` Xcode menu:

[image]

I don't know, however, if you can opt-out and not have it downloaded.

Comment: Thank you. I am just starting Apple development, and I wasn't sure if the built-in docs were complete or if something was still downloadable separately like before--but in an obscure way.